# Plotting graphs using loops in R

Tags: r, loops

My code is as follows, I'm trying to use a loop to get R to plot 24 different graphs, but I keep getting the error code "number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length"

```
array.1 <- array(dim=c(24,2))
array.1[,1] <- c("g1","g2","g3","g4","g5","g6","g7","g8","g9","g10","g11","g12","g13","g14","g15","g16","g17","g18","g19","g20","g21","g22","g23","g24")
array.1[,2] <- c("fiveac"   ,"fiveem",  "k3en","    k3ma",  "k3sc", "k3EnMaSc", "gender",   "SECshort", "hiquamum", "singlepar",    "house",    "fsm",  "parasp","computer",    "tuition"   ,"pupasp"   ,"homework",    "attitude"  ,"sen"  ,"truancy"  ,"absent"   ,"exclude", "IDACI_n",  "FSMband")
for(i in 1:24){
  array.1[i,1] <- ggplot(ks4.dat, aes(x=array.2[i,2], y=ks4score))
  array.1[i,1] <- array.1[i,1] + geom_point()
  array.1[i,1] <- array.1[i,1] + geom_smooth(method="lm")
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to print out the plots or save them into variables in order to access later?

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is that you cannot store a ggplot in an array:

```r
library(ggplot2)

a <- array(1, dim = c(1,1));  
d <- data.frame(x = rnorm(10), y = rnorm(10)); 
g <- ggplot(d, aes(x = x, y = y)) + geom_point()
a[1, 1] <- g
#> Error in a[1, 1] <- g: number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
```

<sup>Created on 2020-02-20 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Perhaps you could try a named list instead?

Obviously, I don't have your data to work with, but you could try:

```
glist <- list()
for(i in 1:24){
  gglist[[i]] <- ggplot(ks4.dat, aes(x=array.1[i,2], y=ks4score))
  gglist[[i]] <- gglist[[i]] + geom_point()
  gglist[[i]]] <- gglist[[i]] + geom_smooth(method="lm")
}
```

I also noticed that you are trying to index an object called `array.2` in your call to ggplot. Is this a mistake?